# How can I store an Expression in List with proper Separation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I am trying Parenthesis Matching (Unbalanced or Balanced ) Program using stack and Have a Doubt in this...

How Can i store an Expression in a List with Proper Separation ..

i was tried by storing the expression as String but also there was a problem like if an user give input like

```
exp = "2*3+11+2"

for i in exp:

    print(i)
Output :
for the 11 it will print 1 1 (two times)
```

How can i store in List.. i mean if an User give Input

like = `(2*3)+(4*60)/3`
it should store like `[(,2,*,3,),+,(,4,*,60,),/,3]` so that i can traverse through it properly and check for the ( or ) parenthesis

i can do it by space input like 2 + 3 (by using split() function )
but what to do if an user is not giving input by spacing ?

Comment: if it is not a competetitive coding problem and you are doing some real problem, you can try `regex` `re.findall(r'\d+|.{1}', '(2*3)+(4*60)/3')`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean by:

```
import re
exp = "2*3+11+2"
print([i for i in re.split('(\D)', exp) if i.strip() != ''])
```

Output:

```
['2', '*', '3', '+', '11', '+', '2']
```

Comment: They probably also want whitespace characters to be removed, and to group digits/floats together.

Comment: @ExaltedToast Ohh maybe, edited my answer, thanks

Comment: @U11-Forward 
exp = "2*3+11+2"
print(list(exp.replace(' ', ''))) for 11 it will store like  ` ['2', '*', '3', '+', '4', '/', '2', '*', '1', '1'] ` 11  will store with 1,1(which is not correct)

Comment: @PallabTewary Edited my answer, should work now

Comment: @U11-Forward 11 will print with 2 separate 1's

Comment: @PallabTewary Edited my answer, definitely should work now

Comment: Wouldn't work correctly for `'(2*3)+(4*60)/3'`. Use `(\D)` without the `+`

Comment: @U11-Forward  its working but for exp = `'2+3(3*2)'` why it's printing an Extra Space > `Output ['2', '+', '3', '(', '3', '*', '2', ')', '']`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as short and concise as the other suggested answers, but it may be more understandable, and it uses the builtin `tokenize` library, so someone else has already solved the problems for you. Here's an example boiled down from the [`tokenize` Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#examples)

```py
from tokenize import tokenize, ENCODING, ENDMARKER, NEWLINE
from io import BytesIO
def tok_string(exp: str):
    token_gen = tokenize(BytesIO(exp.encode("utf-8")).readline)
    result = list()
    for token in token_gen:
        print(token)
        if token.type not in (ENCODING, ENDMARKER, NEWLINE):
            result.append(token.string)
    return result

print("FIRST EXAMPLE")
print(tok_string("2*3 +11+2"))
print("\n SECOND EXAMPLE")
print(tok_string("(2*3)+(4*60)/3"))
```

generates the output:

```
FIRST EXAMPLE
TokenInfo(type=62 (ENCODING), string='utf-8', start=(0, 0), end=(0, 0), line='')   
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='2', start=(1, 0), end=(1, 1), line='2*3 +11+2') 
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='*', start=(1, 1), end=(1, 2), line='2*3 +11+2')    
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='3', start=(1, 2), end=(1, 3), line='2*3 +11+2') 
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='+', start=(1, 4), end=(1, 5), line='2*3 +11+2')    
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='11', start=(1, 5), end=(1, 7), line='2*3 +11+2')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='+', start=(1, 7), end=(1, 8), line='2*3 +11+2')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='2', start=(1, 8), end=(1, 9), line='2*3 +11+2')
TokenInfo(type=4 (NEWLINE), string='', start=(1, 9), end=(1, 10), line='')
TokenInfo(type=0 (ENDMARKER), string='', start=(2, 0), end=(2, 0), line='')
['2', '*', '3', '+', '11', '+', '2']

 SECOND EXAMPLE
TokenInfo(type=62 (ENCODING), string='utf-8', start=(0, 0), end=(0, 0), line='')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='(', start=(1, 0), end=(1, 1), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='2', start=(1, 1), end=(1, 2), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='*', start=(1, 2), end=(1, 3), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='3', start=(1, 3), end=(1, 4), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string=')', start=(1, 4), end=(1, 5), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='+', start=(1, 5), end=(1, 6), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='(', start=(1, 6), end=(1, 7), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='4', start=(1, 7), end=(1, 8), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='*', start=(1, 8), end=(1, 9), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='60', start=(1, 9), end=(1, 11), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string=')', start=(1, 11), end=(1, 12), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=54 (OP), string='/', start=(1, 12), end=(1, 13), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='3', start=(1, 13), end=(1, 14), line='(2*3)+(4*60)/3')
TokenInfo(type=4 (NEWLINE), string='', start=(1, 14), end=(1, 15), line='')
TokenInfo(type=0 (ENDMARKER), string='', start=(2, 0), end=(2, 0), line='')
['(', '2', '*', '3', ')', '+', '(', '4', '*', '60', ')', '/', '3']
```

As you can see, there's a lot more information provided by the `tokenize`-er that you may want to take advantage of.